# What is preventing a VS 2003 aspx web form from opening in the designer?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2003, asp.net-1.1

I'm trying to open an .aspx file in Visual Studio 2003 and I receive the error "The file could not be loaded into the Web Forms designer...The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed." The file then opens displaying the HTML and not the web forms designer.

[image]

This is a new installation of VS 2003 on a Windows XP virtual machine. The same .aspx file opens fine on another XP pc. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the only reasonable recommendation would be to stop using Windows XP and VS2003. I know business sometimes forces you to use old stuff, but that's just ridiculously old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away after I installed [Visual Studio 2003 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=703).